Nginx + React - incomplete chunked encoding
I creating a telegram webapp. Build and run Docker container. It's work perfectly fine. But on my phone i received Script Error in my telegramm app. On PC evryting worked.
I tried some solutions:
install older version of webpack.
update node in docker.
And now im here :c
App doesnt work on my https / http domain in browser anymore. But works by host IP and on localhost.
In browser console:
GET http://www.{{domain}}/static/js/bundle.js 
net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)

Nginx configuration file:
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name {{domain}} www.{{domain}};

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9040/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /parser/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9010/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /provider/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9001/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /create/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9003/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/{domain}/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/{domain}/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

Other servers like: /create/ or /parser/ - works fine.
What could be reason? Evry change that i make before, im already rollback. But something isnt work now.

I dont know wtf was that. Reconfigure nginx using Nginx Proxy Manager. Now evrything works fine.
